# How to include a yaml template between 2 different tasks in the another template in Azure pipeline deployment

Tags: templates, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml, build-pipeline

I'm new to yaml pipeline deployments, Can any point me to the right direction on how to include a yaml template between different tasks in the main template in Azure pipeline deployment.

I have created build.yaml file which has several tasks. Now I need to include/call/use another template (which has some tasks) in between the tasks in build.yaml

how can we achieve this ?

[image]

Comment: Can you add to your question the yaml and the template you want to insert?

Comment: have added the screenshot, hope this will help to understand.

Comment: Did you refer to the YAML pipeline documentation? It includes extensive examples of how to use templates.

Answer (score 4):

You can directly insert a [step template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#step-templates) between two tasks in a job like as below.

- **step-template.yml**

```yaml
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Insert step'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: echo "This step is inserted form the templates."
```

- **azure-pipelines.yml**

```yaml
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Before inserted step'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: echo "This step is before the inserted step."

- template: step-template.yml

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'After inserted step'
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: echo "This step is after the inserted step."
```

**Note:** You can only insert Step templates between tasks in a job. The [Job templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#job-templates) and [Stage templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example%2Cparameter-schema#stage-templates) are not available.